# Are there Light side powers and "Light Jedi"?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force

To put into context, Force powers such as Force Lightning are considered exclusively Dark side powers. Dark Jedi are defined as Force users who have succumbed to the Dark side, yet are not officially a member of either the Jedi or Sith Orders. I assume most readers understand the distinction between Dark Jedi from Jedi or from Sith, so I shall not elaborate further.

So first, what are the equivalent Light Side-exclusive powers? I've seen Light Side-only powers in games, but I hope to cross-reference with actual lore to be certain they aren't Light Side exclusive for game balancing and mechanics alone. Other than that, the Light Side is described as more powerful than the Dark Side, relying on knowledge instead of sheer power to prevail, though is harder to master. This leads me to believe there do exist ways of using the Force through the Light to be learnt that cannot be gained through the Dark.

Secondly, are there "Light Jedi"? Force users who are aligned with the Light Side or simply do not use the Dark Side, but aren't members of the Jedi or Sith Orders. Ahsoka Tano comes to mind, but technically she had Jedi training. Dark Jedi, however, are generally considered to be inferior in training and Dark Side expertise compared to Sith, so I'm not sure if Ahsoka can be considered a legit Light Side equivalent of Dark Jedi by definition. Care to enlighten me on this? Thanks!

Comment: Is any of that canon?

Comment: Sitting in conference rooms discussing things seems to be a power that Light Side Force Users alone do.

Answer (score 6):

The most obvious example of a light side power would be Force ghosting:

> The ultimate goal of the Sith, yet they can never achieve it; it comes only by the release of self, not the exaltation of self. ( ROTS novelization )

If we bring Legends EU into it, there are other powers such as "Wall of Light":
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_light

Comment: Darth Vader did that, right?

Comment: Anakin Skywalker did that, after ceasing to *be* Darth Vader ( and through the assistance of Obi-Wan & Yoda ). By the same token, the former "Master Dooku" used lightning.

Answer (score 5):

With the restructuring of canon, much of this is not very clear. But [this wiki article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Light_side) does name a number of light side powers, noting that

> Light-sided Force abilities are virtually all defensive and passive in nature. While there are light side abilities for increasing ones strength or courage, or incapacitating an enemy, none of them are truly aggressive (with the notable exceptions of Electric Judgment, Sever Force, and Combustion).

As far as non-Jedi "light side" users, there  certainly were some, though they may be further from Jedi than Dark Jedi were from Sith:

- The [Jensaarai](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jensaarai)
- The [Fallanassi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fallanassi)
- The [Aing-Tii Monks](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aing-Tii)
- The [Baran Do](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Baran_Do)

All of whom showed varying levels of light-side affiliation. Additionally, there were [Gray Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gray_Jedi), which may refer to Jedi who skirted boundaries or operated outside the Order, though in both cases they were still *technically Jedi*.

Comment: I seem to recall somewhere in EU was a Jedi or adept who's special power was "Force empathy." (I believe this was also -- according to EU -- Leia's strength as well, which served her well as a diplomat.)