# Can all Jedi/Sith learn the same Force powers?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, jedi, sith, revenge-of-the-sith

Are all Force powers available to all Force users, regardless of if they're light or dark side? Or, are some powers only accessible to those who exclusively associate (and practice) with a given side of the Force.

For example, in episode III, Yoda uses Force lightning against Palpatine, and Mace Windu uses dark side techniques when saber fighting with Palpatine. This might suggest that Force powers can be obtained regardless of affiliation. But then there are also instances, such as the conversation between Anakin and Palpatine in the concert hall, where some Force powers are described as being obtainable only through practicing that given side of the Force.

> PALPATINE: (continuing) Did you ever hear the tragedy of Darth Plagueis "the wise"?
>
> ANAKIN: No.
>
> PALPATINE: I thought not. It's not a story the Jedi would tell you. It's a Sith legend. Darth Plagueis was a Dark Lord of the Sith, so powerful and so wise he could use the Force to influence the midi-chlorians to create life ... He had such a knowledge of the dark side that he could even keep the ones he cared about from dying.
>
> ANAKIN: He could actually save people from death?
>
> PALPATINE: The dark side of the Force is a pathway to many abilities some consider to be unnatural.

So, which is it? Could Yoda, if he wanted to, learn all the powers of the dark side too? Or, is it the case that once you commit to a certain side of the Force, then there are some powers that you can never learn?

Comment: Force lightning is accomplished by *disfiguring* (corrupting) the Force. Yoda could learn to do it, but only at the cost of turning to the dark side. Note that he doesn't create the lightning, merely turns it back on its creator.

Comment: At this point, none of the things you're describing are spoilers. And even if they were, the way to hide them is to use a spoiler tag >!

Comment: Possible dupe of [Are there Light side powers and “Light Jedi”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94021/are-there-light-side-powers-and-light-jedi)

Comment: @Valorum Since I'm fairly new to this portion of SE, I had been wondering how to use the spoiler tag...thanks for this!

Comment: Possible dupe of [Is Force lightning part of “Jedi powers”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132875/is-force-lightning-part-of-jedi-powers)

Comment: @Valorum No, I'm am specifically concerned with if some Force powers are no longer accessible once someone commits to a side of the Force. Or, if they could (if they wanted) turn to the other side, and still learn everything of that side.

Comment: You can't turn to the dark side and become a Force spirit when you die. You can't be a Jedi and use Force Lightning. You can, however, switch sides if you have sufficient willpower

Comment: Are you asking if people are incapable of performing certain feats (no matter how much they try), or whether some feats need to be trained specifically (not just stemming from general force aptitude)? I.e. does it hinge on advanced studies, or the capability of doing it when you already fully understand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This has been demonstrated by Grey Jedi, like Jolee Bindo and Kyle Katarn, both being able to use lightning and heal, for example.

There are some limiting factors however, that don't make it easy. The paths of Jedi and Sith are different. Sith are very impulse-driven, which would mean that they rashly use powers of the dark side to quickly overcome any obstacles in their way with power or just for amusement. Jedi are conditioned from start of their training to resist the dark side and use powers only when necessary and in a harmonious way. This would lead to each of the sides to specialise just in their own applications of the force, and lacking practice in the other.

Palpatine alludes to the fact that dark side is a big taboo for the jedi temple and hence a jedi practitioner of it would be expelled from the jedi order.

Comment: Some examples of the Grey Jedi you mention using both Light and Dark side moves would be nice

Answer (score 1):

We have one good example - Count Dooku a.k.a. Darth Tyranus. Former Jedi Master, he must have known a lot about Light Side powers. And, as a Sith lord, we know he had Dark Side powers like Force Lightning.

Main question is, was he able to use them in same period, i.e. could he use Light Side powers while he was Sith Lord ? Answer is ambiguous, because in Canon there are no specific Light Side powers excepts Force Ghost technique, which was not known to most of Jedi so Dooku never even known that it exists.

What is certain is to use Dark Side powers, you would need to tap to Dark Side energies and emotions. That doesn't mean you would instantly become "evil" (prime example is  Luke using Dark Side to defeat his father on Death Star 2 ), but constant use would certainly have determinable effect.

Answer (score -3):

It is my understanding that anyone Good or Bad could learn any lesson. The force is neither good nor bad, it simply is. The user of the force determines the outcome by his or her intent. The force is also limited by the individual person trying to use it. If they lack the power to wield it, that particular power/lesson becomes unattainable. The original force users used both sides of the force. Peace of mind as well as emotion. One force split by to paths so to speak.

Hope this helped

Comment: Can you support your opinion with a quote?

Comment: BEN Well, the Force is what gives a Jedi his power. It's an energy field created by all living things. It surrounds us and penetrates us. It binds the galaxy together.

BEN Remember, a Jedi can feel the Force flowing through him. LUKE You mean it controls your actions? BEN Partially. But it also obeys your commands.                    If you take just this small quote, to me, it says its neutral and anything is possible

Comment: @RonnieChambers I'm not sure that this conversation is best to go off of, since this is the absolute first lesson Luke has about the Force, so, perhaps Ben is simplifying things.. I mean, Ben does "lie" to Luke literally right after that, in the very same conversation (when talking about his dad).

Comment: @RYAN LANDELS - If you have relevant evidence (such as a quote) that no one else has submitted, it's generally better to post a new answer yourself, with that evidence included, rather than adding that evidence to someone else's existing answer via an edit. It's entirely legitimate to submit essentially the same answer or explanation as someone else, if you're also posting better evidence than the other user did.